# If $f$ is continuous on $[a,\infty)$ and increasing on $(a,\infty)$, can we say $f(x)>f(a)$.

Tags: calculus

If $f$ is continuous on $[a,\infty)$ and increasing on $(a,\infty)$ can we say $f(x)>f(a)$ for $x>a$.

I think yes, the fact that $f$ is (strictly) increasing on $(a,\infty)$ gives,

$$f(x)>f(y)$$

For $x,y \in (a,\infty)$ with $x>y$, in particular take $y=a+.0000000....01$ or $y=a+\epsilon$ with $\epsilon>0$, the inequality holds and $f(a+\epsilon) \to f(a)$ by continuity.

But I don't know how to make a rigorous proof.

Comment: Surely you can make that conclusion without continuity from the definition of increasing? (presumably, 'increasing' meaning 'strictly increasing' here)

Comment: @Shuri2060 Are you saying that the condition on continuity is unnecessary?

Comment: I don't think so, take $f(x)=x^2$ for $x>0$ with $f(x)=5$ for $x=0$, we do not have $f(x)>f(0)=5$ for all $x>0$. @Shuri2060

Comment: Ah I see - my bad. We need continuity for the first point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x>a$, let $t$ be in $(a,x)$, and assume that $f(a)>f(t)$.

Since $f$ is continuous on $[a,t]$, by the Intermediate Value Theorem

there is a number $c$ in $(a,t)$ with $\displaystyle f(c)=\frac{f(a)+f(t)}{2}>\frac{f(t)+f(t)}{2}=f(t)$.

Since $c<t$ with $f(c)>f(t)$,  this gives a contradiction.

Therefore $f(a)\le f(t)<f(x)$.

---

(edited to correct the error pointed out by Furrane)

Comment: Why is $c<x$? ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: It is chosen to be in $(a,x)$.

Comment: Thanks! ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: You proven that " $f(x)>f(x)$ for some $x>a$ " is false. Which means only that $x>a \Rightarrow f(a)\le f(x)$, not $x>a \Rightarrow f(a) <  f(x)$.

Comment: Can't this be fixed by assuming $f(a) \geq f(x)$.

Comment: @Furrane Thank you for pointing out this error.  (Hopefully I have fixed it.)

Answer (score 2):

This is true, the problem is only weak inequalities are preserved under limits (can you prove it?). You can overcome this: Take $z>a$, then there are $x,y$ such that $z>y>x>a$ (why?). We have $f(z)>f(y)>f(x)$. Take $x\rightarrow a$.

Comment: How would one go about the limits preserve weak inequality?

Comment: The nice thing about this argument is that it only requires continuity from the right at a, not continuity on $[a,\infty)$.

Answer (score 2):

This holds true if $f$ is **strictly** increasing, which means :

$$\forall x \in (a,+\infty), \forall y>x : f(y)>f(x)$$

In particular :

$$\forall x\in (a,+\infty), f(x)>f\left(a+{x-a\over2}\right)\ge f(a)$$

But if $f$ in increasing (not strictly) well you could have for example :

$$\forall x \in (a,+\infty), f(x)=f(a)$$

Which is obviously not compatible with $f(x)>f(a)$

If $f$ is increasing, the best comparaison you can have is :

$$\forall x \in (a,+\infty), \forall y>x : f(y)\ge f(x)$$

Which would lead to :

$$\forall x \in (a,+\infty), f(x)\ge f(a)$$

Comment: How do you know that $f((x+a)/2)\geq f(a)$?

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if wrong:

Let $f$ be continuous on $[a,n]$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and strictly increasing on $(a,n]$.

1) min {$f(x) | x \in [a,n]$} = $f(a)$.

The continuous function $f$ on a closed interval attains its minimum.

Assume the function has its minimum at $x_0 \gt a$.

Then $f((x_0 + a)/2)  \lt f(x_0)$ since $f$ is strictly increasing on $(a,n]$.

Contradiction, since $f(x_0)$ was assumed to be the minimum.

Hence min {$f(x)| x \in [a,n]$} = $f(a)$.

2) $f(a) \lt f(x)$ for $x \gt a$.

Since $f(a)$ is the minimum on $[a,n]$ we have

$f(a) \le f(x)$ , $x \in [a,n]$.

It remains to be  shown  that

$f(a) \lt f(x)$ , $x \in (a,n]$.

Assume for an $x_1 \gt a$ we have $f(a) = f(x_1)$.

Consider $x_2 = (x_1 + a)/2  \lt x_1$.

It follows $f(x_2) \lt  f(x_1) = f(a)$, the minimum, since $f$ is stricly increasing and  $x_2  \lt x_1$.

A contradiction.

Now the other case:

Let $f$ be increasing in $(a,n]$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

1) $f$ has its minimum at $x = a$ as before,

I.e. $f(a) \le f(x)$ for $x \in (a,n]$.

Proof by contradiction:

Assume there is an $x_1 \gt a$ such that $f(x_1) \lt f(a)$.

$f$ is continuous on $[a,x_1]$.

Intermediate Value Theorem:

There exists a point $p \in [a,x_1]$ with $f(p) =( f(a) + f(x_1))/2$.

Note:  $f(x_1) \lt f(p) \lt f(a)$.

We have $p \ne a$ ; $p\ne x_1$,

I.e. $a \lt p \lt x_1$.

Thus $f(p) \gt f(x_1)$,  where $p \lt x_1$,

a contradiction to f being an increasing function.

Conclusion:  $f(a)$ is the minimum, hence $f(a) \le f(x)$ , for $x \gt a$.